# Is there a way to save a frozen tensorflow graph in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I know that you can save a model into a checkpoint or SavedModel with Python. I want to know if there is a way to save the GraphDef returned from FreezeSavedModel C++ function using C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function FreezeSavedModel returns a *GraphDef*-Object. You can save this object with *WriteBinaryProto* or *WriteTextProto*

```
//BinaryProto
const string binary_file = io::JoinPath(testing::TmpDir(), "binary_graph.pb");
TF_ASSERT_OK(WriteBinaryProto(Env::Default(), binary_file, graph_def));

//Textproto
const string text_file = io::JoinPath(testing::TmpDir(), "text_graph.pbtxt");
TF_ASSERT_OK(WriteTextProto(Env::Default(), text_file, graph_def));
```

You can find an example within [file_utils_test.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d9ca72348fab0a289e5e73b5d1addc5aff3a35a3/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/file_utils_test.cc)